# You do not have permission to perform this action

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am facing this issue while trying to add users to  SP group using REST and Jquery.

While adding the user prompt comes asking for username and password, after I enter my credentials it does not authenticate, but after canceling this prompt error comes saying

> "you do not have permission to perform this action"

Again when I check in the group the users has been added already. I am able to perform delete action without any issue.

here is my code below.

```
function addUsers(name)
     { 
    var loginName = name.split('|')[1].split('\\'); 
    var domain = loginName[0]; 
    var userid = loginName[2]; 
    var requestUri = varSiteUrl + "_api/web/sitegroups(" + $("#ddlgroup").val() + ")users";
     $.ajax({ 
    url: requestUri,
     type: "POST",
     data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName': domain + '\\' + userid }),
    headers: { "accept": "applicationjson;odata=verbose", "content-type": "applicationjson;odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue },
    success: onSuccess, error: onError
     }); 
    }
```

This is working properly with Site collection Admin access but does not work with Full control access.